# Angular template is not updated on beforePrint event

Tags: angular, angular-template, onbeforeprint

I would like to update my template before print it.
So I have used this event: `@HostListener("window:beforeprint", ["$event"])`

But the template is updated too late; after closing the print window.

I have tried the `matchMedia` event but same.
I also tried to use `NgZone` but without success.

You can test here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-before-print-event

> /!\ The Stackblitz console is not the right. You need to open the DevTool console to see the right message at the right time

Do you have any suggestion ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeprint_event) :

```
The beforeprint event is fired when the associated document is about to be printed or previewed for printing.
```

So it happens when the preview is launched, not before it's launched.

You can move the logic inside your `printme()` function and use the **ChangeDetectorRef** to update your template :

```js
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public printMe(): void {
    this.message = "before print triggered ";
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    window.print();
  }
```

Comment: oups ok
I can't do this solution simply because it's not the same components etc...
I need a service or effect...
But ok I understand why, I'll look into it.